# Is Field Day a contest?

Tags: united-states, contest, field-day

Is the ARRL Field Day a contest, or is it not a contest?

*Kindly explain the reasoning behind your answer.*

A non-ham could not tell the difference.

Comment: I am asking this due to [**this discussion in this chat room**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95353/discussion-on-question-by-zeiss-ikon-how-do-field-day-participants-protect-from).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this affiliated club document](https://www.qsl.net/ta1dx/afet/fieldnedir.htm), yes, Field Day is a contest.

> Field Day is a competitive event sponsored by the American Radio Relay
>   League (ARRL). The objective is for participating individuals and
>   organizations to:
>
> ```
>     Go to a location where there is normally no communications capability.
>     Create one.
>     Contact as many stations as possible during the operating period.
>     Tear the site down, and pack it away for a real emergency.
> ```

The document goes on to discuss techniques for efficiently maximizing number of contacts by exchanging the minimum required information (call sign, station type, section) and "moving on."  This document doesn't talk about scoring, but I've encountered many references to "bonus points" for this and that (for instance, if I were to operate for the club, my recent license would be worth extra points for each QSO; the visit we received from an ARRL official was, I was told, worth 100 bonus points).

If it's a competitive event, with scoring, it's a contest.  No awards, no plaques, etc. just make it a "bragging rights" contest.

Answer (score 6):

No, Field Day is not a contest, because stations do not submit logs for checking to validate the claimed scores. No plaques or other commemorations of competitive achievement are sponsored or awarded by ARRL, the sanctioning organization.

That does not stop participants from *behaving* as though Field Day is a contest. Inasmuch as a primary goal of the activity is to exercise hams' ability to communicate effectively under field conditions, the number of contacts made on various bands using various modes over a 24-hour period is a useful surrogate measurement of performance.

Experienced Field Day participants often develop specialized skills. These can include:

- Planning: equipment, antennas, power, shelter, security, safety, RFI and powerline noise abatement, hospitality
- Construction and teardown: antenna supports, electrical distribution and communication networks, station habitats, chuck wagon
- Operation: band, mode and time-of-day specialties
- Recruiting, mentoring and organizing individuals into effective teams

While many Field Day operations may fall into broad categories, no two Field Day operations are identical, depending as they must on the skills of the individuals that are available to participate in any given year. It is this dynamic nature of the challenge that keeps so many of us coming back year after year.

Comment: And yet there are "points" scored in some way,  And, seemingly, a point bonus for getting a visit from an ARRL official...

Comment: And, many other bonus point opportunities, too. But, as with the logs, most of those are not checked for validity. They do, however, stimulate interest and activity among those with various specialties.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because score is kept and the rankings get published.

No, because no monetary prize is allowed and enforcement of rules is done by the "contestants" with no real verification.

Comment: Just **which amateur radio contests award money**? I thought that the FCC made doing so illegal many decades ago.

Comment: Some field day event organizers try to get member involvement to the max by members setting up local club challenges between the perspective area clubs & groups, etc. Sometimes, for outstanding achievement (fo the previous year), special acknowledgement through clubs &/or organizations, may be awarded. In most cases, in the form of memberships, educational tuitions & supplies, even trip expenses to, special radio related events. Only "Amateur Radio Flea Markets" with 'door prizes' or 'raffle ticket' sales, (that I know of) offer chances for prizes, or maybe cash too, but I doubt it. Never seen

Comment: Yes **AND** No? ;-)